# KIVY : Image + Label inside dynamic buttons

Tags: android, python, kivy

I want to show Image+label inside dynamic buttons that created in a for loop. The problem is its showing the image+label layout only in the last button. How do I can display it in all buttons?

**main.py**

```
class HomeScreen(Screen):
    grid_l = ObjectProperty(None)
    top_lbl = ObjectProperty(None)

    def search_btn_pressed(self):
        grid = self.grid_l
        grid.bind(minimum_height=grid.setter('height'),
                     minimum_width=grid.setter('width'))

        for i in range(3):
                layout = GridLayout(cols=1)
                print layout
                img = Image(source='kivy.png')
                print img
                lbl = Label(text='label')
                layout.add_widget(img)
                layout.add_widget(lbl)

                btn1 = Button(size_hint=(1, None))
                btn1.text = '%r' % i
                btn1.add_widget(layout)

                grid.add_widget(btn1)
```

.kv

```
#:kivy 1.7.2

<HomeScreen>:
    scroll_view: scrollviewID
    top_lbl: lblID
    grid_l: gridlayoutID
    AnchorLayout:
        size_hint: 1, .1   
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .9}
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
        Label:
            id: lblID
            text: 'Button Tester'
    Button:
        size_hint: 1, .1   
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .8}
        text: 'Press me!'
        on_release: root.search_btn_pressed()
    ScrollView:
        id: scrollviewID
        orientation: 'vertical'
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
        size_hint: 1, .8
        bar_width: '8dp'
        GridLayout:
            id: gridlayoutID
            cols: 1
            size_hint: 1, None
            row_default_height: 40
            row_force_default: False
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually not displaying only for the last button - it's displaying for each button, but in the same position. The problem is that `Button` is not a layout, and as such, does not perform layout of its children. So the `GridLayout` for each button is rendered at `0, 0` with size `100, 100` relative to the origin of the nearest relative parent (in this case, the `GridLayout`  `grid_l` because it is contained by the `ScrollView`).

When you add widgets to a non-layout widget, it's up to you to layout those widgets by setting position and size. Note that you must set the actual `pos` (or `x` and `y`) and `size` (or `width` and `height`) - you cannot use `pos_hint` or `size_hint`, as those are only handled by layouts.

This can be done easily using [dynamic classes](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html#dynamic-classes) in [kv language](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html):

```
<CustomButton@Button>:
    image_source: ''
    subtext: ''
    GridLayout:
        height: self.parent.height  # match the button's height
        width: 100                  # set to whatever you would like
        pos: self.parent.pos        # match the button's position
        cols: 1
        Image:
            source: root.image_source
        Label:
            text: root.subtext
```

To use your dynamic class, you will need to import [`Factory`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.factory.html):

```
from kivy.factory import Factory
```

Then, in your loop:

```
for i in range(3):
    btn = Factory.CustomButton(text=str(i), size_hint=(1, None),
                               image_source='kivy.png', subtext='label')
    grid.add_widget(btn)
```

Finally, a side note: you're creating new bindings on `grid_l` every time `search_btn_pressed()` is called. These bindings should only be created once. You could bind once in Python by moving those bindings to `HomeScreen.__init__()`, but again, this is easier in kv:

```
    GridLayout:
        id: gridlayoutID
        cols: 1
        size_hint: 1, None
        row_default_height: 40
        row_force_default: False
        height: self.minimum_height   # bind height to minimum_height
        width: self.minimum_width     # bind width to minimum_width
```